# MariaDB randomly crashes

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2, mariadb, crash

I've encountered a peculiar issue related to my MariaDB database instance (version 10.2) that causes my MariaDB service to stop unexpectedly. I've attempted to investigate the problem by regularly logging the RAM usage of the top 3 processes for every minute using a cronjob, aiming to determine if MariaDB consumes excessive memory before the server crashes. However, after conducting this investigation, I'm inclined to believe that excessive RAM usage is not the root cause of the issue.

Additionally, whenever the server crashes, I've attempted to review the MariaDB logs using the following commands:

- `sudo cat /var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log` - This command returns no
  results.
- `sudo systemctl status mariadb -l` - This command yields the
  following output:

[image: Result of command]

Also, here is screenshot of the OS information:

```
[someuser ~]$ uname -a
Linux ec2.internal .amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 8 01:29:11 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[someuser ~]$ hostnamectl
   Static hostname: <ip>.ec2.internal
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: -
           Boot ID: -
    Virtualization: xen
  Operating System: Amazon Linux 2
       CPE OS Name: cpe:2.3:o:amazon:amazon_linux:2
            Kernel: Linux <ip>.amzn2.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

I would greatly appreciate your assistance in diagnosing and resolving this server stability problem. Any insights and guidance on how to proceed would be invaluable.

---

Answers to the comment from @NikitaKipriyanov:
Hi @NikitaKipriyanov, thank you for questions. Following your advice I ran `dmesg -T | grep mysql` and found out this (pasting only the relevant data):

```
[Mon Sep 18 17:37:34 2023] [  26231]    27 26231    29965       52    61440        0             0 mysql-prepare-d
[Tue Sep 19 14:04:29 2023] [  26839]    27 26839   367222    19121   630784        0             0 mysqld
[Tue Sep 19 14:04:31 2023] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/,task=mysqld,pid=26839,uid=27
[Tue Sep 19 14:04:31 2023] Out of memory: Killed process 26839 (mysqld) total-vm:1468888kB, anon-rss:76484kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:27 pgtables:616kB oom_score_adj:0
[Tue Sep 19 14:05:41 2023] [  29800]    27 29800     2326       26    61440        0             0 mysql-check-soc
[Tue Sep 19 14:05:52 2023] [  29800]    27 29800     2326       26    61440        0             0 mysql-check-soc
```

As we can see the date and time kinda matches when the service has stopped working. Something I want to mention is that when I run dmesg -T I see more often that the web server httpd has crashed:

```
[Tue Sep 19 14:13:00 2023] [  30195]     0 30195   143596     2011   839680        0             0 httpd
[Tue Sep 19 14:13:00 2023] oom-kill:constraint=CONSTRAINT_NONE,nodemask=(null),cpuset=/,mems_allowed=0,global_oom,task_memcg=/,task=httpd,pid=28937,uid=48
[Tue Sep 19 14:13:00 2023] Out of memory: Killed process 28937 (httpd) total-vm:628120kB, anon-rss:11732kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:96kB, UID:48 pgtables:860kB oom_score_adj:0
[Tue Sep 19 14:13:17 2023] systemd-journald[30073]: Received SIGTERM from PID 1 (systemd).
```

However, the web server has never experienced crashes or interruptions in its operation. The issue only affects the MariaDB service. The issue comes from time to time only to the MariDB service for e.g. every 3 to 5 days.
These are the only logs I only have in /var/log/mariadb folder:

```
[root@ip mariadb]# ls -la
total 28
drwxr-x---  2 mysql mysql  146 Sep 20 03:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 root  root  4096 Sep 26 03:23 ..
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql    0 Sep 20 03:48 mariadb.log
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql 8714 Sep  7 12:40 mariadb.log-20230908
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql 2005 Sep 15 18:02 mariadb.log-20230916.gz
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql 1917 Sep 18 17:39 mariadb.log-20230919.gz
-rw-------  1 mysql mysql 1909 Sep 19 14:16 mariadb.log-20230920.gz
[root@ip mariadb]# pwd
/var/log/mariadb
```

Here is also the output of `sysctl -A | grep panic` :

```
[root@ip log]# sysctl -A | grep panic
fs.xfs.panic_mask = 0
kernel.hardlockup_panic = 0
kernel.hung_task_panic = 0
kernel.panic = 30
kernel.panic_on_io_nmi = 0
kernel.panic_on_oops = 0
kernel.panic_on_rcu_stall = 0
kernel.panic_on_unrecovered_nmi = 0
kernel.panic_on_warn = 0
kernel.panic_print = 0
kernel.softlockup_panic = 0
kernel.unknown_nmi_panic = 0
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.all.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.default.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.eth0.stable_secret"
sysctl: reading key "net.ipv6.conf.lo.stable_secret"
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
```

---

Answers to Wilson Hauck questions:

Regarding RAM:

```
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           964M        333M        197M        724K        433M        451M
Swap:            0B          0B          0B
```

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;` - 238

`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;` - Returns too many rows to be pasted here, which value are you looking for

`SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;`- Same

How should I send the output of all requested queries?

Comment: Please do not post links to images of text

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions to stabilize your system.

Comment: The **FIRST** place to start diagnosing faults on a server host is in its logs. ALL the logs. The most likely cause is the OOMKiller.

Comment: `dmesg`, anything else particular in `/var/log`? Also, is it the whole server crashes or only MariaDB service? How does that look? What are the kernel panic parameters (attach `sysctl -A | grep panic`)? **Attach everything textual as text, please, and remove screenshots. We want all of that to be indexed as text, possibility to copy-paste, etc., and live in the question, not on some third party site.**

Comment: So fine, what's in `dmesg`? Just run this command as root immediately after it crashes again, better `dmesg -T` to see wall clock timestamps, and show us the relevant output (e.g. grep away audit events etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Do I get a prize for guessing correctly?

There's lots of answers here and elsewhere on the internet on how to address this. Unfortunately a lot of them are wrong. If they mention oom_adj or oom_score_adj then this is NOT how to fix your issue.

There are 2 things you need to do.

The first is to look at your configuration for your webserver and the database (and presumably there some application tier in here as well) to ensure that they don't try to use up more RAM than you have available. Since you didn't tell us about the application server nor the webserver I can't really advise (but here's [a hint for pre-fork Apache](http://lampe2e.blogspot.com/2015/03/accurate-capacity-planning-with-apache.html), optionally with PHP). As for Mariadb - go get a copy of [mysqltuner.pl](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl/master/mysqltuner.pl) and run it against your installation.

That should prevent you running out of memory most of the time, but you should also reduce the amount of non-existent memory the kernel will hand out:

```
sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=2
sysctl vm.overcommit_ratio=20
```

...and try lower values for the ratio if you are still seeing OOM killer.

Comment: The webserver is running on php using CodeIgniter framework, how I usually start everything is `sudo systemctl start httpd` `sudo systemctl start php-fpm` and `sudo systemctl start mariadb`. . Also, the application connects to the database using a file database.php which contains the fiollowing parameters: dsn, hostname, username, password, database, dbdriver, dbprefix, pconnect, db_debug, cache_on, cachedir, char_set, dbcollat, swap_pre, encrypt, compress, striction, failover, ave_queris. Unfortunately, I cannot put the output in this comment as there are some restrictions in comment section